# Jenkins plugin drop-down menu

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

Somehow I am not able to store values from drop-down menus, that I added to the jelly.xml for my Jenkins plugin. Text fields work just fine on the other hand

jelly:

```
<f:entry title="Catch+ Version" field="selection">
  <f:select/>
</f:entry>
```

I added nothing to the databound constructor. Maybe this is already the problem. I didn't know how to add it, since it's not a string but a list?!

So I only added the doFillSelectionItems function, which works as it should.

```
public ListBoxModel doFillSelectionItems()
{
    return new ListBoxModel(new Option("1.13", "1.13"),
                    new Option("1.14", "1.14"),
                    new Option("1.15", "1.15"));
}
```

and also to the configure method before save():

```
catchVersion = formData.getString("selection");
```

I can change between the three Options and the value is stored, no doubt. I can run the build several times and it's using the selected value, BUT: if I go to configure project again, always the first option is selected, no matter what I had chosen before. How can I make the stored value appear here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third parameter to the Option constructor which defines the current selection. You can also pass the current value in

```
public ListBoxModel doFillSelectionItems(@QueryParameter String selection) {
    return new ListBoxModel(new Option("1.13", "1.13", selection.matches("1.13") ),
                    new Option("1.14", "1.14", selection.matches("1.14") ),
                    new Option("1.15", "1.15", selection.matches("1.15") ));
}
```

Adapted from [here](http://cleantestcode.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/how-to-write-a-jenkins-plugin-part-2/) but this is an example using the global config

Comment: This was similiar to what I already tried. But unfortunately this just makes the list empty. If I click on the drop down menu, nothing appears anymore.

Comment: Oh my, sorry I was wrong. I missed the "@QueryParameter String selection" as argument of the doFill function. Now I added it and it works. Thanks a lot! :)