# optional block in jelly.config not translating to the backend in jenkins plugin development.

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-jetty-plugin, jelly

I have jelly.config with the following:

```
        <f:block>
            <f:optionalBlock inline="true" name="dynamic" title="Mandatory parameter for rpm artifacts only" checked="false"
                help="/plugin/artifactory/help/common/help-artifactType.html">
                        <f:entry title="Operating System">
                                <select class="setting-input" name="operatingSystem">
                                        <option value="rhel5">rhel5</option>
                                        <option value="linux">linux</option>
                                </select>
                        </f:entry>
                        <f:entry title="Architecture">
                                <select class="setting-input" name="architecture">
                                        <option value="64">64</option>
                                        <option value="32">32</option>
                                </select>
                        </f:entry>
            </f:optionalBlock>
        </f:block>
```

In my serverDetails.js I have :

```
    public class ServerDetails {
    public final String operatingSystem;
        /**
         * This the type of operating system that your rpm builds on. If not specified, this passes null. 
         */
        public final String architecture;
        /**
         * This the type of architecture your rpm runs on. If not specified, this passes null. 
         */
    }

    public ServerDetails(String artifactoryName, String artifactoryUrl, String repositoryKey, String snapshotsRepositoryKey,
                             String downloadReleaseRepositoryKey, String downloadSnapshotRepositoryKey,
                             String downloadReleaseRepositoryDisplayName, String downloadSnapshotRepositoryDisplayName,
                             String userPluginKey, String userPluginParams,String artifactKey,String productKey, String operatingSystem, String architecture, String buildType) {
            this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
            this.architecture = architecture;
            this.buildType = buildType;
            createStagingPlugin();
        }

public ServerDetails(String artifactoryName, String artifactoryUrl, String repositoryKey, String snapshotsRepositoryKey,
                         String downloadReleaseRepositoryKey, String downloadSnapshotRepositoryKey,
                         String downloadReleaseRepositoryDisplayName, String downloadSnapshotRepositoryDisplayName) {
        this(artifactoryName, artifactoryUrl, repositoryKey, snapshotsRepositoryKey, downloadReleaseRepositoryKey,
                downloadSnapshotRepositoryKey, downloadReleaseRepositoryDisplayName, downloadSnapshotRepositoryDisplayName, null, null,null,null, null, null, null);
    }
```

In my backend java I use this as :

```
public String getOperatingSystem() {
        return details != null ? details.operatingSystem : null;
    }

    public String getArchitecture() {
        return details != null ? details.architecture : null;
    }
```

Now when I access operating system and architecture after selecting them in fronted I still get null values for both of them when I print it out.

Am I missing something here ? Why am I not getting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your created job, what does the XML have? You can get this from the URL localhost:8080/job//config.xml

I would guess that you need a `doFillOperatingSystemItems` call like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608598/jenkins-plugin-drop-down-menu)

**untested**

```
public ListBoxModel doFillOperatingSystemItems(
    @QueryParameter String operatingSystem
) {
    return new ListBoxModel(
        new Option("rhel", "rhel", operatingSystem.matches("rhel") ),
        new Option("linux", "linux", operatingSystem.matches("linux") ) 
    );
}
```

Comment: I get this from config.xml :

false true false false false false -22811212@1424728182186 dev nuget test **rhel5 64** http://djin-artifact01.dowjones.net:8081/artifactory true false asasas *password*,*secret* false true false

I see just the default values of operating system and architecture being shown here. Also I tried adding doFillOperatingSystemsItems to my class file that has the data bound constructor but that doesn't get called. Is it automatically called or whats the process ?

Comment: okay got it, worked now thanks! Could you take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870278/values-in-jelly-config-not-persisting-in-the-front-end-but-being-saved-in-the-ba